# Dojo custom build with gridx - Still files are downloaded when page loaded?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo.gridx, gridx

We are using dojo in our product extensively and recently all pages with Enhanced grid were updated to gridx and its working fine.

We had compressed gridx files into dojo through Dojo custom build without errors ( i have included all these js files into profile.js file and gridx folder is at the same level where dojo,dijit,dojox are there),i still see my pages requesting few gridx/modules files when page is loaded.

[image]

Can someone tell how to avoid downloading these files.

This is profile.js used,its trimmed down to show only gridx related files.

```js
var profile = (function() {
  return {
basePath: "./",
releaseDir: "blinkx",
releaseName: "dojo_lib22",
action: "release",
layerOptimize: "closure",
optimize: "closure",
cssOptimize: "comments",
mini: true,
stripConsole: "warn",
selectorEngine: "lite",
resourceTags: {
  amd: function(filename, mid) {
    return false;
  }
},
packages: [{
  name: "dojo",
  location: "dojo"
}, {
  name: "dijit",
  location: "dijit"
}, {
  name: "dojox",
  location: "dojox"
}, {
  name: "gridx",
  location: 'gridx'
}],
layers: {
  "dojo": {
    include: ["gridx/nls/gridx",
      "gridx/modules/extendedSelect/Column",
      "gridx/modules/extendedSelect/Cell",
      "gridx/modules/extendedSelect/_RowCellBase",
      "gridx/modules/extendedSelect/_Base",
      "gridx/modules/AutoScroll",
      "gridx/modules/select/Row",
      "gridx/modules/CellWidget",
      "gridx/modules/NavigableCell",
      "gridx/modules/Edit",
      "gridx/core/model/extensions/Modify",
      "gridx/core/model/extensions/Mark",
      "gridx/modules/HiddenColumns",
      "gridx/modules/RowLock",
      "gridx/core/model/cache/Async",
      "gridx/core/model/cache/Sync",
      "gridx/core/model/_Extension",
      "gridx/core/model/Model",
      "gridx/core/Row",
      "gridx/core/Column",
      "gridx/core/Cell",
      "gridx/core/_Module",
      "gridx/core/model/extensions/Query",
      "gridx/modules/Header",
      "gridx/modules/View",
      "gridx/modules/Body",
      "gridx/support/query",
      "gridx/modules/VLayout",
      "gridx/modules/HLayout",
      "gridx/modules/VScroller",
      "gridx/modules/HScroller",
      "gridx/modules/ColumnWidth",
      "gridx/modules/Focus",
      "gridx/modules/Pagination",
      "gridx/modules/pagination/PaginationBar",
      "gridx/support/Summary",
      "gridx/modules/Bar",
      "gridx/support/LinkPager",
      "gridx/support/LinkSizer",
      "gridx/support/GotoPageButton",
      "gridx/support/GotoPagePane",
      "gridx/modules/SingleSort",
      "gridx/core/model/extensions/Sort",
      "gridx/modules/Filter",
      "gridx/core/model/extensions/ClientFilter",
      "gridx/modules/filter/FilterBar",
      "gridx/modules/filter/FilterDialog",
      "gridx/modules/filter/FilterPane",
      "gridx/modules/filter/DistinctComboBoxMenu",
      "gridx/modules/filter/FilterConfirmDialog",
      "gridx/modules/filter/FilterTooltip",
      "gridx/modules/filter/QuickFilter",
      "gridx/support/QuickFilter",
      "gridx/modules/Puller",
      "gridx/modules/VirtualVScroller",
      "gridx/modules/Menu",
      "gridx/modules/ColumnResizer",
      "dijit/form/FilteringSelect",
      "gridx/modules/RowHeader"
    ],
    customBase: true,
    boot: true
  }
}
  };
})();
```

Comment: Please provide your profile.js

Comment: Edited my question,i have included only gridx related files as including other files path related to dojo,dijit etc.. is huge.

Comment: Have you checked if the dojo.js loaded by your page is the one generated by the build ? and if yes, did you open that file to check if there was references of the files you still see in the console ?